# Array Index out of bound for loop

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Taxi {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int groups = input.nextInt();
        int counter=0;

        int[] pass = new int[groups];

        for(int i=0; i<groups; i++){
            pass[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<groups; i++){
            if(pass[i]==4)
                counter++;

            else if(pass[i]+pass[i+1]<=4){
                counter++;
                i++;
            }
            else 
                counter++;
        }

        System.out.println(counter);
    }

}
```

**keep on receiving error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Taxi.main(Taxi.java:21)
```

**please help**

Comment: This is a perfect time to learn to read error logs and basic debugging, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else if(pass[i]+pass[i+1]<=4)` line is your killer definitely.

the reason is you are using for loop with `i < groups`

```
 for(int i=0; i<groups; i++)
```

so `i+1` goes to equals to groups for the last iteration.

say for example , it the groups size is `5` then for loop becomes

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
```

we can have `group[0] ... groups[4]` max
and `groups[5]` `causes` `array index out of bound exception`.

if we check for loop like above then when `i` goes to `4` then it satisfies for loop check as `4<5` and enters for loop but there you are doing `pass[i]` -> ok but `pass[i+1]` will become like `pass[5]` which definitely causes array index out of bound exception

so check for loop like below

```
 for(int i=0; i<groups-1; i++)
```

it will work now even for the last element.

Answer (score 3):

This line appears to be causing the exception:

```
else if(pass[i]+pass[i+1]<=4){
```

You're limiting `i` to be less than `groups`, which is the size of the array, but then you deliberately run off the end by using `i+1`.

Check if `i` is less than one less than `groups` first.

```
else if ( (i < groups - 1) && (pass[i]+pass[i+1]<=4)){
```